# Hybrid phone echo cancellation circuit

Tags: telephone

I'm using a single board computer to talk on a phone line through two coils, one for the TX part, the other for the RX. The phone line is on another coil and then it's connected to a two-wire circuit that leads to an handset.
As you know, the problem with this config is that if you build a full-duplex communication system with VoIP in the middle, you hear the echo from what you just transmitted on the network coming back [See this connection scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBevM.png)

Is there a circuit which is able to reduce or eliminate such echo? Right now I'm using a DSP to implement a simple subtractor (Rx=Rx-Tx), but maybe this common problem has been solved by clever analogue engineers back in the past.

[Connection scheme with echo path in red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBevM.png)

Comment: Related: [What methods can be used to identify and remove echo from an audio system?](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/338/what-methods-can-be-used-to-identify-and-remove-echo-from-an-audio-system)

Comment: @Kellenjb thank you! My specific question would be about a circuit which does that "automatically", exploiting the magnetic circuit or something like that.

Comment: Yeah, I understand its not a duplicate, just close enough that I figured it was worth linking to.

Answer (score 6):

The analogue circuit is known as a "two-wire hybrid" and does exactly what you are doing with your DSP. Strictly speaking this is just [sidetone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sidetone) elimination rather than echo cancellation which Kellenjb's link addresses. Below is a simple example (which is a discrete replacement for an obsolete [Mitel part](http://www.zarlink.com/zarlink/hs/82_MH88524.htm)). This arrangement only works if the load impedance is precisely controlled - in this case 754\$\Omega\$.

[image]